# How to connect to redis server with init file and no passwd

Tags: php, class, redis

First, I have wrapper Datasource class for connecting redis server.

And I have a init file of ip port and passwd etc;

The content redis.ini.php file is:

```
<?php
 $config['redis']['instance1'] = array(
'default' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '6379',
    'timeout' => 5,
    'pconnect' => 1,
    'password' => '',
   )
  );
 $config['redis']['instance2'] = array(
'default' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '6379',
    'timeout' => 5,
    'pconnect' => 1,
    'password' => '',
 )
);
```

And the code of class Datasource.php is:

```
<?php

namespace common;

class Datasource {

 public static $config_name;  

 public static $server_region;  

 public static $redis_config;

public function __construct() {}

public static function getRedis($config_name = NULL, $server_region = 'default') {


  self::$config_name=$config_name;
  self::$server_region=$server_region;

    global $config;
    self::$redis_config = $config['redis'][$config_name];

    if (self::$config_name && self::$redis_config && self::$server_region) {

        try {
            self::$redis = new \Redis();
            self::$redis->connect(self::$redis_config[$server_region]['host'], self::$redis_config[$server_region]['port']);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            self::$redis = null;
        }

    } else {
       self::$redis = null;
    }

    return   self::$redis_config[$server_region]['host'] ;
  }
 }
```

Now, I want to use this class in html code:

```
<body style="height:100%" >

<?php 
include "o1ws1v/class/common/Datasource.php";
include 'o1ws1v/conf/redis.ini.php';
$redis_obj = common\Datasource::getRedis('instance1');
echo $redis_obj;
?>
</body>
```

But unlucky, I can not get corrent value:127.0.0.1 in html .

I have found that the problem was try{}catch{}, when i delete these code, it work fine.

```
//delete these code, it works fine
try {
 self::$redis = new \Redis();
 self::$redis->connect(self::$redis_config[$server_region]['host'], self::$redis_config[$server_region]['port']);

  } catch (Exception $e) {
            self::$redis = null;
   }
```

I have asked one question one hour ago in stackoverflow, sorry about one more question. My boss claim me to solve this question today.

I have defined my redis server with no password for logging. It seems nothing wrong for connecting redis server, Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this porblem

```
 self::$redis = new \Redis();// it is wrong
 $redis=new \Redis();//it is right
```